# Qt Creator search/replace with regexp while editing : forcing capture to uppercase

Tags: regex, search, replace, qt-creator

I want to replace all occurences of 'XYZ_lowercaseword' by 'Lowercaseword', i.e., remove a prefix and make the new first letter uppercase.

With Qt Creator regexp, I can easily search for XYZ_([a-z]) which will match 'XYZ_something' and capture the 's' of 'something'. How to refer to the captured group in the replace field while forcing it to go uppercase ? This should then be enough, right ?

Comment: Any new developments regarding this to date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at least up and until Qt Creator 3.6.1, there's no built-in functionality that would do that. You'll have to use an external tool or modify the search code to add that functionality.

There has been long-time support for capture groups, provided via `QString::replace`, i.e. you can have capture groups referenced in the replacement text.

To refer to capture group `n`, use the syntax `\n`, where `n` is an integer. E.g. in your case, you'd refer to capture group 1, and the replacement would be `XYZ_\1`. Unfortunately, there's no way to change the case using this syntax.

Comment: Can I at least reuse the captured elements, even without modifications to them ?

Comment: @C.THIN Unfortunately not, unless I'm really misreading the code.

Comment: Ok, then what side solutions would recommend for refactoring ? Maybe some quick perl interface, maybe vim ?

Comment: @C.THIN Ideally, a Qt Creator plugin. It's not hard to make one, and you're already using Qt presumably. It should be short. Maybe I'll write one just to see how much work it'd take.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Qt, so in fact I don't know about plugins, though 1) I ain't surprised to learn there are Qt Plugins and 2) I'm surprised I haven't searched for one myself. Keep me up to date if you come to any result.

Comment: @C.THIN There are Qt plugins, but that's not what I'm talking about. You're using Qt *Creator*, an IDE written in Qt, and that IDE is completely plugin-based. All of its functionality comes from plugins :)

Comment: Makes sense. And so, either I get an existing plugin for advanced regexp find/replace, or I write on myself. Any adive as to either or both ?

Comment: Qt Creator 2.8.1 support reusing captured elements from a RegEx search, but I didn't see a way to replace with an upper case letter.
For example: Find String: "XYZ_([a-z])([^\s]*)"  -- Replace String "XYZ_\1\2" works fine to find and replace, but changing ReplaceString to "XYZ_\U\1\E\2" doesn't work for capitalizing the first letter.

Answer (score 3):

To use regex group capture in QtCreator use advanced search (control + shift + f) with use regular expressions turned on

search for your regex, e.g.

`XYZ_([a-z])([a-z])+`

Click the Search & Replace button

use \1 to insert the captured group (\2 for group 2, etc) e.g.

`\1\2`

to replace

`XYZ_lowercaseword`

with

`lowercaseword`

Tested in QtCreator 3.6.1

Comment: Does not address the first letter that needs to be uppercase.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Qt Creator but I read it use the Perl dialect so you can try this

Replace

```
XYZ_(.*)
```

With

```
\u${1}
```

Comment: Seems Qt uses a subset of the Perl symbols and capabilities.